# react router rendering <noscript> in client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

In the server side it renders fine, but when it gets to the client side the react part of html vanishes and I get this error:

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
(client) <noscript data-reacti
(server) <div data-reactid=".z
```

this is my client code before compression:

```
import {Router, RouterContext, browserHistory} from "react-router";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


const innerHTML = document.getElementById('react-routes').innerHTML;
const routes = JSON.parse(innerHTML);
console.log(routes);

// ReactDOM.render(<RouterContext {...routes} />, document.getElementById('react-app'));

ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes.routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('react-app'));

// Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
//   React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('app'));
// });
```

I've tryed this three methods the two firsts gives the same error and the third says that Router.run is not a function. (the third was what I had working a few version ago)

the HTML generated by the server is this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="react-app"><div data-reactid=".1rbyhm4ruo0" data-react-checksum="-854297298"><span data-reactid=".1rbyhm4ruo0.0">Hello </span><span data-reactid=".1rbyhm4ruo0.1">BLBALBLABA LUIZ</span><div data-reactid=".1rbyhm4ruo0.2"><input type="text" value="Login" data-reactid=".1rbyhm4ruo0.2.0"><span data-reactid=".1rbyhm4ruo0.2.1">Hello </span><span data-reactid=".1rbyhm4ruo0.2.2">Login</span></div></div></div>

    <script id="react-routes" type="application/json">{"routes":[{"name":"public","path":"/","childRoutes":[{"name":"login","path":"/login"}]},{"name":"login","path":"/login"}],"params":{},"location":{"pathname":"/login","search":"","hash":"","state":null,"action":"POP","key":"zc9mx1","query":{},"$searchBase":{"search":"","searchBase":""}},"components":[null,null],"history":{},"router":{"__v2_compatible__":true},"matchContext":{"history":{},"transitionManager":{},"router":{"__v2_compatible__":true}}}</script>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/bundle.js"></script>


</body></html>
```

and after the client runs it becames this:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-app"><noscript data-reactid=".zhdkkenpq8"></noscript></div>

    <script id="react-routes" type="application/json">{"routes":[{"name":"public","path":"/","childRoutes":[{"name":"login","path":"/login"}]},{"name":"login","path":"/login"}],"params":{},"location":{"pathname":"/login","search":"","hash":"","state":null,"action":"POP","key":"qbhof0","query":{},"$searchBase":{"search":"","searchBase":""}},"components":[null,null],"history":{},"router":{"__v2_compatible__":true},"matchContext":{"history":{},"transitionManager":{},"router":{"__v2_compatible__":true}}}</script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/bundle.js"></script>


</body></html>
```

I'm using the same method to renderToString() in the server.

Thanks

Comment: just notice this "components":[null,null] in the json of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was actually in gulp while browserifying the project.
As I'm creating dynamic routes to react-router, I don't have all the react classes being imported while gulp is running and it don't add the right packages to my bundle.js.

I want to make it fully dynamic, I'll keep on working on a better solution for this problem, but for the time being I could make it run by bundling *.react.js.